# How to make Android app content load faster

Tags: android, performance, server

I have an Android app developed with Android studio. There is an admin panel on my server (shared hosting) where I add, delete and modify all the photos and text of the app.

I wanted to know if there is a way to make the content of the app load even faster for the user. Such as server requirements, settings, any additional programs, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/) to send and receive data from server.

Also you can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) for loading images faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Morteza. I will look into your suggestions.